# Question finding matching numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am new to python and was messing with lists and loops. I want to make a dice game and roll the dice 5 times, store it in a list then find numbers that match in said list. but the out put ends up just giving me the value of the the list length.

````
import random
        
#I start with an empty list
            
dice = []
            
#Roll 5 random numbers
            
for x in range(0, 5):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    dice.append(x)
            
#find how many time a number in the list was rolled
            
count = 0
for x in range(6):
    count = dice.count(x)
                
print(“Player rolled:”, dice)
print(count)
        
#The output ends up this:
#Player rolled: [3, 3, 3, 1, 3]
        
#[5]
        ```
#output value I'm looking for is 4
        
#output next run
#Player rolled: [2, 6, 5, 6, 6]
        
#[5]
# output value should be 3
#How do I find and store the matches in the list and store them in count? Sorry #I’m really trying to understand lists and loops but I just can’t figure this out
````

Comment: Zeek, your code is still not aligned properly. Can you please fix it. What do you expect `count` to be printed? The last instance of the `for` loop or every instance of the `for` loop?

Comment: I'm just trying to find the number of matching numbers in the list and store it in count. Player rolled: [3, 3, 3, 1, 3] should be count = 4 because 4 numbers are the same. count is players matches or should be.

Comment: What if the numbers rolled were `[3,1,2,2,3]` ? Should it say 2?

Comment: you should check `if count > max_count` if yes, then `max_count = count`. Then print `max_count`. See my code below

Comment: I'd say yes I was just trying to make like a poker hand type game so in that case it would be 2 as in 2 pair. I did see you code it should help me out a lot. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Print max times a dice landed on a number

## Also, print the numbers on the dice

Here's the updated code that also prints the numbers that were rolled max times. I am storing the numbers that were rolled max times into a list. If there is a new max_value, then i am resetting the list to store the new number. If the max_value (counts) is the same as the previous max count, then I am appending to the list (as there are two of them).

```
import random

#I start with an empty list
    
dice = []
    
#Roll 5 random numbers
    
for x in range(5):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    dice.append(x)
    
#find how many time a number in the list was rolled
    
count = 0
max_count = 0
max_value = []

print('Player rolled :', dice)
for x in range(1,7):
    count = dice.count(x)
    if max_count < count:
        max_count = count
        max_value = [x]
    elif max_count == count:
        max_value.append(x)
    print(x, 'was rolled :', count , 'times')

print ('max times a number was rolled is :', max_count)
print ('following numbers were rolled max times :', max_value)
```

The output of a few runs are:

```
Player rolled : [3, 1, 5, 2, 3]
1 was rolled : 1 times
2 was rolled : 1 times
3 was rolled : 2 times
4 was rolled : 0 times
5 was rolled : 1 times
6 was rolled : 0 times
max times a number was rolled is : 2
following numbers were rolled max times : [3]

Player rolled : [3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
1 was rolled : 0 times
2 was rolled : 0 times
3 was rolled : 2 times
4 was rolled : 0 times
5 was rolled : 2 times
6 was rolled : 1 times
max times a number was rolled is : 2
following numbers were rolled max times : [3, 5]
```

## Print the max times a dice landed on a number

I think you want to find out how many times each number was rolled. If so, you need to print count each instance of the for loop.

Here's the code that would do it.

```
import random

#I start with an empty list
    
dice = []
    
#Roll 5 random numbers
    
for x in range(5):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    dice.append(x)
    
#find how many time a number in the list was rolled
    
count = 0
max_count = 0

print('Player rolled :', dice)
for x in range(1,7):
    count = dice.count(x)
    if max_count < count:
        max_count = count
    print(x, 'was rolled :', count , 'times')

print ('max times a number was rolled is :', max_count)
```

The output of this will be:

```
Player rolled : [6, 5, 5, 1, 5]
1 was rolled : 1 times
2 was rolled : 0 times
3 was rolled : 0 times
4 was rolled : 0 times
5 was rolled : 3 times
6 was rolled : 1 times
max times a number was rolled is : 3

Player rolled : [2, 2, 3, 6, 5]
1 was rolled : 0 times
2 was rolled : 2 times
3 was rolled : 1 times
4 was rolled : 0 times
5 was rolled : 1 times
6 was rolled : 1 times
max times a number was rolled is : 2
```

Comment: "max times a number was rolled is : 2" This is what I am trying to do thank you. so much

Comment: excellent. I think you were just missing the part where you check the value of count. If this solved the question, please feel free to mark as answered and upvote the answer.

Comment: Yeah, only been doing this python thing for a week and I'm still figuring out how stuff works this may be a bit more then I should of tried at this point..

Comment: You are doing great. Keep going. Python is easy to learn and its fun too.

Comment: You asked me "What if the numbers rolled were [3,1,2,2,3] ? Should it say 2?" how would I make that work?

Comment: See the new code. It also prints the dice numbers if its max times. In the above case, it will be `max count = 2, numbers are [2,3]`